# Where is BILLING_RESULT_OK defined?

Tags: android

[BillingClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient) offers a method named [isFeatureSupported()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.html#isFeatureSupported(java.lang.String)). The documentation for the int returned is:

> BILLING_RESULT_OK if feature is supported and corresponding error code otherwise.

I could not find BILLING_RESULT_OK to be defined anywhere. It is not among the constants defined in [BillingClient.BillingResponse](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.BillingResponse). Should I just use

```
BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK
```

?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

in 2019 running `'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.0.1'`
replace:
 `BillingResponse.OK` 
with
 `BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK`
The whole documentation feels very unprecise. Shocking to see how weak Google handles this.

Comment: In 2019 BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK perfectly!

Comment: Yes all the tutorials still say "BillingResponse". I wonder why they changed it?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that's a typo in the documentation. Instead, you should use `BillingResponse.OK`: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.BillingResponse#ok

You can see it in use in this example:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive_v2/shared-module/src/main/java/com/example/billingmodule/billing/BillingManager.java#L126

Comment: import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient.BillingResponse; Is not work! error: cannot find symbol class BillingResponse

Answer (score 1):

For me useing `BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK`did not work, it always acts like if the feature is not supported. I had to use this:

```
int response = billingClient.isFeatureSupported(BillingClient.FeatureType.SUBSCRIPTIONS);
if (response == BillingClient.BillingResponse.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Feature not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So whole check for "com.android.billingclient:billing:2.0.3" looks like this:

```
public boolean isSubscriptionsSupported() {
  if (myBillingClient != null) {
      BillingResult isSubscriptionsSupported = myBillingClient.isFeatureSupported(BillingClient.FeatureType.SUBSCRIPTIONS);
      return isSubscriptionsSupported.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK;
  }
  return false;
}
```